# Firefox: "Some parts of this page are not secure, such as images." What counts as insecure?

Tags: ssl, firefox, ssl-certificate

I use the browser Firefox, and sometimes, on certain webpages, the SSL icon says "Some parts of this page are not secure, such as images." What, exactly, counts as an insecure element?

Thanks!

Comment: It means the images (or fonts, or whatever static assets) are not being pulled in over `https`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Anything that is delivered over an insecure channel.

What this generally means is that the developer of the web page is combining HTTP-based URLs with HTTPS-based URLs in the same page. The URLs could be for images as well as JavaScript, CSS, or anything else that can be referenced from a web page. As a user, there's not much you can do about this -- it's a warning that there is a possibility that your data could be delivered to other servers in an open, unencrypted manner over the Internet. This is a Bad Thing, but you can't do much except avoid that site, or contact the support or webmaster for the site.

If you're the developer, most of the time you can use a scheme-relative URLs when referencing images or javascript, etc.

i.e. Instead of this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/dot.png">
```

use this:

```
<img src="//example.com/dot.png">
```

YMMV.

See also: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: is there a tool that lists which URLs are insecure?  Does Firebug do this?  an online tool?

Comment: All of the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge) running on Windows will tell you. Press F12 to bring up Developer Tools for your site. On IE, Edge, and FF, look at the Network tab. They list the Protocol (IE/Edge), or use an icon in the Domain column (FF) to show HTTP vs HTTPS. Chrome has a Security tab; it lists each kind separately. Alternately, you can use Fiddler instead (that's what I would use).

Answer (score 14):

In firefox you can see in Inspect Element=>Network Tab=>Domain Columns.
And also please check in Console tab too.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: It was the SSL trust logo image that was causing the issue, looking into console tab helped.

Answer (score 3):

"Insecure" simply means "not loaded via HTTPS".

This is insecure:

```
<img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
```

This is secure:

```
<img class="media-object" src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
```

Answer (score 0):

"Some parts of this page are not secure, such as images." 
means not all content are are loading with secure https you can use this online tool to determine which resource is loading with http  [whynopadlock](https://www.whynopadlock.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is My Solution

To resolve this issue make sure that the page code does not pull data directly from a non-secure URL.

View the page source html code to check for non-secure items.  This can be done in a web browser by doing a right click and selecting 'view source'.

To identify non-secure elements view the source code of the page and search for the text src="http://
This will then highlight elements on your page being loaded from a non-secure URL.

The source code (HTML) needs to be checked for NON SECURE tags. (i.e. http://www.symantec.com/images/seals/Secure...)  Ensure the following references are changed to HTTPS or a virtual directory.

Note:  The webmaster should always be consulted prior to any adjustments made to a web site. 
  Thank You and I hope this will Help out

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress users that can't find any 'http:' in the page source check if you have a favicon set. Wordpress will default to their W icon (w-logo-blue.png) and I've had a couple sites continue to serve it from http even after fully converting to ssl.

Dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize -> Site Identity -> add a site icon

Answer (score 0):

***FOR IMAGES***
First of all, check whether your image file has HTTP instead of HTTPS if so change it to https or rather save those images and put in in the Server.
For instance,
`<img src="http://example.com/images/image.jpg">`(http image source)
to
`<img src="https://example.com/images/image.jpg">`(https image source)or into
`<img src="//example.com/images/image.jpg">`(server image)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox throws an error when you have **mixed active content**. This is having a combination of HTTP and HTTPs requests; it's a security issue as it leaves room for man in the middle attack- intercepting HTTP content requests with malicious or unwanted requests.

Tip: Check all the following urls in your active content:

- < script >
- < link >
- < iframe >
- < XMLHttpRequest >
- fetch()
- urls in CSS (@font-face,cursor,background.image)
- < object >
- Navigator.sendBeacon (look for url)

Another tip: make sure to check all files (css gets overlooked)